# call .jar from php.....need server configuration?

Tags: java, php, jar

I hope not to duplicate a post but I could not find any details about it.

I developed a java sendMail application (with NetBeans) and correctly compiled the project.
I copied everything on my UNIX cloud server in the same path where the php resides where I need to call the .jar.
the following is the structure of the path:

```
/file.php
/SendMail.jar
/lib/javax.mail.jar
```

When i call file.php (via browser), nothing happens......
I have tried all syntax possible in php......shell_exec....exec....ecc...ecc...
below the code I am using:

```
$java = "/opt/abs/httpd/SendMail.jar";
shell_exec("java -cp ".$java);
echo "Done";
```

**do I have to implement some configuration for the apache server to communicate with java?**

where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you try to manually execut the application? Do you pass any parameters? Your posted code doesn't do so but sending mails would need parameters (e.g. the email address), wouldn't it?

Comment: Did you face any error? What is output of your script?

Comment: without parameters because are hardcoded....from...to....connection....ecc...ecc...

Comment: oops.......i found 1 error below: 
sh: 1: java: not found
.....but .jar exist....

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

> You should first package the project with every dependency needed in a jar file.

**Step 2:**

> Then try running the jar on your local machine using:

```
java -jar /path-to-jar/SendMail.jar 
//once you verify everything is working
```

**Step 3:** on your server

```
exec('java -jar /path-to-jar/SendMail.jar')
```

*If you wish to run it in background*

```
exec('java -jar /path-to-jar/SendMail.jar > /log-path/yourservice.log 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for STEP 1......I put all the packages in the jar.
Same for step 2....in local Machine .jar run correctly.

STEP 3........I tried exec as you said ..... but it does not work.

for this reason I thought I had to work on the server configuration.